# can i eliminate the white space comes between two jpanels in java see the pic i have uploaded please

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border

[image: this is the image of my gui]
I am making an app attendance manager I which I have a base `jpanel` in which i have two further `jpanels` one for the left and one for the right.
the problem i am getting is the white line between two `jpanels` .
i have made my `GUI` using `netbeans` which provides drag and drop functionality for ease .

I have tried following code

```
SeeAttendanceRightPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

but this is not working i still getting that white difference between those two jPanels .

Comment: You haven't passed any argument try this. `SeeAttendanceRightPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));`

Comment: empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()  and jComp4.setBorder(empty); i have seen this on oracle website https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html but le'me try us suggestion thanks

Comment: nope buddy that's  not  working either.

Comment: Please post [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: _which provides drag and drop functionality for ease_ - the problem is it is not "easy". When you use drag and drop the tool decides where space is used between components. Learn how to create layouts manually. As people have suggested, your layout is easily implemented using a `BorderLayout`. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Comment: so there's no fix for it unless i implement it manually as u suggested ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a **solution** to my own question that white space can be eliminated by setting the **layout of parent** jPanel to **ABSOLUTE LAYOUT**.